# Substituting percentage of words at random indexes in String array

Tags: android, arrays, string, random, words

I have a string like

> This is a very nice sentence

I break it into separate words and store in `String[]` with:

```
String[] words = s.split(" ");
```

How can I take a specific percentage on the total number of words (lets say 2 of 6 words) and substitute these 2 words with something else. My code so far:

```
    //Indexes in total
    int maxIndex = words.length;
    //Percentage of total indexes
    double percentageOfIndexes = 0.20;
    //Round the number of indexes
    int NumOfIndexes = (int) Math.ceil( maxIndex * (percentageOfIndexes / 100.0));
    //Get a random number from rounded indexes
    int generatedIndex = random.nextInt(NumOfIndexes);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, calculate how many words you want to replace:

```
int totalWordsCount = words.length;

double percentageOfWords = 0.20;

int wordsToReplaceCount = (int) Math.ceil( totalWordsCount * percentageOfWords );
```

Then, knowing how many words you want to replace, get that many random indexes, and just swap words at those indexes:

```
for (int i=0; i<wordsToReplaceCount; i++) {
    int index = random.nextInt(totalWordsCount);

    //and replace
    words[index] = "Other"; // <--- insert new words
}
```

NOTE: Just remember that the smaller the number of words, the bigger discrepancy between your percentage, and actual number of words to replace, eg. 20% from 6 words is 1.2 word, which becomes 2 after Math.ceil(), and 2 is 33.33% from 6.

Comment: If I want to have the first two and the last two constant indexes I do it like..int index = random.nextInt((maxIndex-2)-2);

Comment: I want to set boundaries on the totalWordsCount . For example if totalWordsCount is 14 , I want the random numbers from 2 to 12.

Comment: For 14 words, to have random number between 2 and 12, that would be int index = 2 + random.nextInt(11); then work out the formula to be used with your variables. Note: remember that if you have 14 words, max index you want is 13, not 14.